# Find basic trial function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Having a little trouble finding the trial function of the following DE:
y'+2y=xcosx

I am guessing it is Ax(Bsinx + Dcosx)

My book doesn't show any examples for finding the trial function except for the most basic functions like x, sinx etc.

Comment: Since x is linear, you should try $(Ax+B)(C\sin(x) + D\cos(x))$

Comment: Better yet, $(Ax+B)\sin x + (C+Dx)\cos x$

Comment: if the DE was y' +2y=Acosx, would the trial function be AB(sinx +cosx) where A and B are both constants?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Let $m(x) = {e^{\int {2dx} }} = {e^{2x}}$ multiply both sides with m(x)

hence

$\begin{array}{l}
{e^{2x}}y'(x) + 2{e^{2x}}y(x) = {e^{2x}}x\cos x \Rightarrow \\
{\left( {{e^{2x}}y(x)} \right)^\prime } = {e^{2x}}x\cos x \Rightarrow \\
\int {{{\left( {{e^{2x}}y(x)} \right)}^\prime }dx = \int {{e^{2x}}x\cos xdx} }  \Rightarrow \\
{e^{2x}}y(x) = \int {{e^{2x}}x\cos xdx} 
\end{array}$

Now you find the integral $\int {{e^{2x}}x\cos xdx} $ which is easy to calculate

Finally the solution is

$y(x) = {c_1}{e^{ - 2x}} + \frac{1}{5}x\sin x - \frac{{4\sin x}}{{25}} + \frac{2}{5}x\cos x - \frac{{3\cos x}}{{25}}$